# How to track application usage?

Tags: c#

I would like to develop an application (that runs at all times in the background I guess) to track the usage of applications (msword, excel, powerpoint, *.exe, etc.).

I can handle posting the data to a database but don't exactly know where to start with monitoring running applications (when they start, when they stop).  Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can periodically poll a list of the running processes using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()`.

This following code outputs information about starting and exiting processes. Exiting system processes won't be recognized.

```
class Program
{
    struct ProcessStartTimePair
    {
        public Process Process { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExitTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Now; // approximate value
            }
        }

        public ProcessStartTimePair(Process p) : this()
        {
            Process = p;
            try
            {
                StartTime = p.StartTime;
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
            {
                StartTime = DateTime.Now; // approximate value
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ProcessStartTimePair> knownProcesses = new List<ProcessStartTimePair>();
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (!knownProcesses.Select(x => x.Process.Id).Contains(p.Id))
                {
                    knownProcesses.Add(new ProcessStartTimePair(p));
                    Console.WriteLine("Detected new process: " + p.ProcessName);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < knownProcesses.Count; i++) 
            {
                ProcessStartTimePair pair = knownProcesses[i];
                try
                {
                    if (pair.Process.HasExited)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(pair.Process.ProcessName + " has exited (alive from {0} to {1}).", pair.StartTime.ToString(), pair.ExitTime.ToString());
                        knownProcesses.Remove(pair);
                        i--; // List was modified, 1 item less
                        // TODO: Store in the info in the database
                    }
                }
                catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
                {
                    // Would have to check whether the process still exists in Process.GetProcesses().
                    // The process probably is a system process.
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

You probably can simply ignore system processes that don't let you read the HasExited property.

**Edit**

Here's a .net 2.0 version:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ProcessStartTimePair> knownProcesses = new List<ProcessStartTimePair>();
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (!ProcessIsKnown(knownProcesses, p.Id))
                {
                    knownProcesses.Add(new ProcessStartTimePair(p));
                    Console.WriteLine("Detected new process: " + p.ProcessName);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < knownProcesses.Count; i++) 
            [...]
        }
    }

    static bool ProcessIsKnown(List<ProcessStartTimePair> knownProcesses, int ID)
    {
        foreach (ProcessStartTimePair pstp in knownProcesses)
        {
            if (pstp.Process.Id == ID)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note that the code could be improved and only shows the concept.

Comment: What happens when the process disappears?  Do you have to poll every minute to get 1 minute resolution?

Comment: Yes, you would have to pull every minute for that. I would store all the existing processes in a list and check if there are new ones or if some of them have exited.

Comment: Yeah I would think that once the application closes then ExitTime would not be accisble (as it is not running).  I want to be able to say that user 'jdoe' used excel for a total of 44 minutes in July

Comment: I also found that a few minutes ago, some processes also don't let the app read their HasExited property. I'm preparing a code sample now.

Comment: Great code example...just what I was looking for.

Comment: I am forced to work with .Net 2.0.  I assume the ".Select" is a method in the linq namespace...any work around for:
if (!knownProcesses.Select(x => x.Process.Id).Contains(p.Id))                
{
knownProcesses.Add(new ProcessStartTimePair(p));                    Console.WriteLine("Detected new process: " + p.ProcessName);
}

Answer (score 1):

You could poll all top-level windows periodically and record the Window title text; and based on that do some conclusions as to which program are running.

Or you could do it via process name, or a combination.

For enumerating windows, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx, and [here is how to use it in managed code](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html).
For enumerating processes, use the Process.GetProcesses method or see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/enumprocess.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use WMI to be notified when processes start/exit

[A full working example is in a blog post on ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx).

The basics of it (copied from the blog post for posterity):

Create a class that inherits from [ManagementEventWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx)

Inside the constructor, set:

```
this.Query.QueryLanguage = "WQL";
this.Query.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM 
__InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";
this.EventArrived += watcher_EventArrived; // Delegate for EventArrivedEventHandler
```

Make an [EventArrivedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.eventarrivedeventhandler.aspx) like:

```
private void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    string eventType = e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName;
    Win32_Process proc = new 
        Win32_Process(e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"] as ManagementBaseObject);

    switch (eventType)
    {
        case "__InstanceCreationEvent":
            Console.WriteLine("Process Created");
            break;
        case "__InstanceDeletionEvent":
            Console.WriteLine("Process Deleted (Ended)");
            break;
        case "__InstanceModificationEvent":
            Console.WriteLine("Process Modified (possibly still running)");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polling is easy but you should really hook into the win32 events and instead receive notifications of when these things happens.

I have a similar side project to create a "task bar" type application. My goal is for the app to be notified when windows are moved/created/closed so I can use this information for displaying/updating a UI.

[bb4win](http://www.bb4win.org/) app has this "layer" where it can catch different kind of notifications from the system and uses it to create an alternative desktop shell. The source code is avail and is coded in c.

This is the link that I used to get started with the [Win32 Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).